# How to reference Composite ID in Gorm 6 or 7 to prevent IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name

Tags: grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I have this model which works with Gorm3

```
class UserDataPoint implements Serializable {
    User user
    DataPoint dataPoint
    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['user', 'dataPoint']
    }
    static List<Long> getReadDataPointIds(User user, List<Long> locationIds = null) {
        createCriteria().list {
            eq('user', user)
            dataPoint {
                    listing {
                        location {
                            inList('id', locationIds)
                        }
                    }
                }
            projections {
                property('dataPoint.id')
            }
        } as List
    }
}
```

but now it runs this exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given
 name [dataPoint] on this ManagedType [user.UserDataPoint]
```

Some debug allows me to understand what is happening, it seems that GORM remove the user and dataPoint properties from HibernateProperties because the are a part of the Composite ID

```
public abstract class AbstractPersistentEntity<T extends Entity> implements PersistentEntity {
.......

IdentityMapping identifier = mapping != null ? mapping.getIdentifier() : null;
            if(identity == null && identifier != null) {

                final String[] identifierName = identifier.getIdentifierName();
                final MappingContext mappingContext = getMappingContext();
                if(identifierName.length > 1) {
                    compositeIdentity = mappingContext.getMappingSyntaxStrategy().getCompositeIdentity(javaClass, mappingContext);
                }
                for (String in : identifierName) {
                    final PersistentProperty p = propertiesByName.get(in);
                    if(p != null) {
                        persistentProperties.remove(p);
                    }
                    persistentPropertyNames.remove(in);
                }
                disableDefaultId();
            }
......
}
```

So I understand the problem, but I don't know how to fix it ?

how to reference the composite ID and it fields in the projection ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be fixed with this recent version https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/releases/tag/v7.2.1